# How to print next three lines?

Tags: python

I have a large file with following format:

Good day, Jenny. (pending)
Good day, Tommy.
Good day, Henry.
Good day, Mary.
Good day, Austin.
Good day, Eason.(pending)
Good day, Eric.
.....

What I need to do is to print the line that contains the word 'pending' and its following three lines. However, I just know how to print the line that contains the word 'pending'. Some one can help? Here is my simple code:

```
word = 'pending'
with open ('1.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        #line = line.split()
        if word in line:
            print(line)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried?  You are going to want to first look into 1) opening the file and 2) using `readlines` to get all the lines

Comment: Looks like homework. We can help but you need to start yourself first. Look how to read a file, line, split into words. Comment/Edit if you face a difficulty.

Comment: I have re-edited my question and show the code. I am struggling with how to print the next three lines. Maybe you guys can give me some ideas? I don't need to print all the lines. Thanks. @CoryNezin

Comment: I have added my code. I have no idea about how to print the next three lines after the line the contains the word pending, maybe you can give me some ideas? Thanks. @sc0rp1on

Comment: What if another "pending" occurs inside the "next three lines"? Do you ignore it (because you are already printing 3 lines)? Do you restart printing a-new on the count of three? Do you finish printing the original 3 lines and *then* print another set of 3 for each occurrence of "pending" in the previous line(s)?

Comment: @usr2564301 Actually, the design of the file is, if the line contains the word 'pending', the next three lines will not contain it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of variable that indicates whether you have found a 'word' in line.

```
counter=0
word = 'pending'
with open ('1.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        if counter>0:
            print(line)
        counter-=1
        #line = line.split()
        if word in line:
            counter=3
```

Also, what are you expecting if one of the next 3 lines has a pending?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the design of the file is, if the line contains the word 'pending', the next three lines will not contain it anymore

Comment: Could you please explain what does 'counter -= 1' mean? I don't get that.

Comment: counter -=1 decreases the value of counter by 1 (it is like counter=counter-1)

Answer (score 1):

Almost there:

```py
word = 'pending'
i=0
with open ('1.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        if (word in line):
            print(line)
            i=1
        if(i>=1) and (i<4):
            print(line)
            i+=1
```